# RPC Error: excution reverted" when calling a function from next.js

Tags: metamask, dapps, react, solidity-0.8.x

I've looked at similar answers regarding this error, and it seems like the majority of them have to do with using the wrong contract address or the abi. In my case, I do not think this is likely because I am using file saver to update contract addresses every time I redeploy and I am using `npx hardhat clean` before compiling updates to contracts. I've heard some people point out that this error might be due to missing receive() and fallback() functions. In such a case, what is the logic I should put in the functions? I don't quite understand how they work even after reading up on them.

For context, I'm trying to call a `deposit` function on js.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted {code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted'}
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
_runReturnHandlers @ inpage.js:17
_processRequest @ inpage.js:17
await in _processRequest (async)
_handle @ inpage.js:17
handle @ inpage.js:17
_rpcRequest @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
request @ inpage.js:1
request @ VM2565:2
eval @ web3-provider.js?6870:65
send @ web3-provider.js?6870:128
eval @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:572
eval @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:8
__awaiter @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:4
perform @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:549
eval @ base-provider.js?4ba1:1550
fulfilled @ base-provider.js?4ba1:5
Promise.then (async)
step @ base-provider.js?4ba1:7
fulfilled @ base-provider.js?4ba1:5
Promise.then (async)
step @ base-provider.js?4ba1:7
eval @ base-provider.js?4ba1:8
__awaiter @ base-provider.js?4ba1:4
estimateGas @ base-provider.js?4ba1:1545
sendUncheckedTransaction @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:203
eval @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:253
fulfilled @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:5
Promise.then (async)
step @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:7
eval @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:8
__awaiter @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:4
sendTransaction @ json-rpc-provider.js?8679:249
eval @ index.js?b70c:323
fulfilled @ index.js?b70c:5
Promise.then (async)
step @ index.js?b70c:7
eval @ index.js?b70c:8
__awaiter @ index.js?b70c:4
eval @ index.js?b70c:312
_callee$ @ _app.js?e0ad:87
tryCatch @ runtime.js?ecd4:45
invoke @ runtime.js?ecd4:274
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js?ecd4:97
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:3
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:13
_next @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:25
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:32
eval @ _async_to_generator.mjs?1d45:21
depositToJuniorPool @ _app.js?e0ad:78
onClick @ _app.js?e0ad:157
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9097
eval @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:6430
_app.js?e0ad:90 Error:  Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xFDE82216765027A0c15Dff066b16F24d0b6D4E8d","to":"0x765640bf43C65b0B50bE753a2889452ffa883152","data":"0xb6b55f25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.js?dd68:224:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.js?dd68:233:1)
    at checkError (json-rpc-provider.js?8679:76:1)
    at Web3Provider.eval (json-rpc-provider.js?8679:575:1)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (json-rpc-provider.js?8679:6:42)
```

These are the relevant parts of the js:

```
async function depositToJuniorPool(amount) {
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      const juniorPool = new ethers.Contract(juniorPoolAddress, JuniorPool.abi, signer)
      const usdc = new ethers.Contract(usdcAddress, IERC20withDec.abi, signer)
      console.log('juniorPool: ', juniorPool)
      try {
          await usdc.approve(juniorPoolAddress, amount)
          const val = await juniorPool.deposit(amount)
          console.log('val: ', val)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err)
        }
}

}
```

These are the relevant parts for the sol:

```js
  function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable override whenNotPaused withinTransactionLimit(amount) nonReentrant {
    require(amount >= 110, "Must deposit 110 or more");
    uint256 depositShares = getNumShares(amount);
    uint256 potentialNewTotalShares = totalShares().add(depositShares);
    require(poolWithinLimit(potentialNewTotalShares), "Deposit would put the Pool over the total limit.");
    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, amount, depositShares);
    bool success = doUSDCTransfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    require(success, "Failed to transfer for deposit");

    config.getJuniorToken().juniorPoolMintTo(msg.sender, depositShares);
  }


  function juniorPoolMintTo(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyJuniorLendingPool {
    require(canMintForJuniorPool(amount), "Cannot mint: it would create an asset/liability mismatch");
    super._mint(to, amount);
  }

  function doUSDCTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  ) internal returns (bool) {
    require(to != address(0), "Can't send to zero address");
    IERC20withDec usdc = config.getUSDC();
    return usdc.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add at least the stack trace and the full error?

Comment: I added the error I get on the console on the front end. Does this suffice?